# Getting TypeError: '[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructorerror in Safari using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, safari

I am getting the following issue while importing table to excel sheet using JavaScript.

Error:

> TypeError: '[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob( [ csv.buffer ], { type: "text/xls"} )')

I am explaining my code below.

```
function CheckBrowser(){
  var browser=checkBrowser();
   // Generate our CSV string from out HTML Table
  var csv = tableToCSV( document.querySelector( "#sites" ) );
  // Create a CSV Blob
  if(browser=='Safari'){
     var blob = new Blob( [ csv.buffer ], { type: "text/xls"} );
  }else{
     var blob = new Blob( [ csv ], { type: "text/xls"} );
  }


  // Determine which approach to take for the download
  if ( navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ) {
    // Works for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, "output.xls" );

  } else {

    // Attempt to use an alternative method
    var anchor = document.body.appendChild(
      document.createElement( "a" )
    );
    // If the [download] attribute is supported, try to use it
    if ( "download" in anchor ) {
      anchor.download = "output.xls";
      anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
      anchor.click();
    }

  }

  function tableToCSV( table ) {
    // We'll be co-opting `slice` to create arrays
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    return slice.call( table.rows ).map(function ( row ) {
      return slice.call( row.cells ).map(function ( cell ) {
        return '"t"'.replace( "t", cell.textContent );
      }).join( "," );
    }).join( "\r\n" );

  }

}
function checkBrowser(){
  if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) //IF IE > 10
    {
      alert('Edge'); 
      return 'Edge';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ){
         alert('IE');
          return 'IE';
    }
   else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) 
    {
        alert('Opera');
         return 'Opera';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 )
    {
        alert('Chrome');
        return 'Chrome';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1)
    {
        alert('Safari');
        return 'Safari';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) 
    {
         alert('Firefox');
    }
    else 
    {
       alert('unknown');
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to export all table value to a excel sheet but getting the above error in `safari 5.1.7+win-7` environment. It's working in other browser fine.

[Here is my plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EkGqemW6K9se52OZO9Ur?p=preview) code.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: blob not available in safari until 6.0 - though that doesn't explain the error exactly - and 5.1.7 is the last win safari - forget windows safari support, apple did 4 years ago :p

Comment: @JaromandaX : Is there any other way to export html table data to excel sheet using Javascript/Jquery in safari.